# Attempting to connect a second monitor through displayport renders Ubuntu 18 unusable, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, lenovo

I have Lenovo ThinkPad W510 running Ubuntu 18. When I connect my TV through the displayport the system becomes unresponsive - I can move the mouse, but there is no response. The TV screen shows No Video.
If I then disconnect the cable the laptop screen goes black and the only way out is reboot.

This laptop used to run Windows 10 before and displayport worked fine. Then it was Linux Mint and there the displayport also worked. So, I am pretty confident the hardware works.

I am at loss how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: I guess nobody knows... Sigh...

Comment: im having a similar issue - did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. Seems like nobody knows how to approach it.